# Run time exception while accessing JSON string from server

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting a json string back from the local test server as following.

[0,"000SSSBBBB"]

I am not able to fetch the "000SSSBBBB" using JSON object. My code is as following. At run time at following line exception comes as following :

"value 0 at 0 of  type java.lang.Integer can not be converted to jsonobject"

JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

Please help as i am new to json.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a JSONObject that's why you are facing with that Exception.
Java doc is sometimes helpful: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

> JSONObject   getJSONObject(int index) 
>             Get the JSONObject associated with an index.

You should use :

> java.lang.Object  get(int index) 
>             Get the object value associated with an index.

or

> java.lang.String getString(int index) 
>             Get the string associated with an index.

Don't forget to provide a length check before to take an element a given position.
You can do it by that following code for example: jsonArray.length() == 1

Answer (score 0):

You can try this!
This [0,'000SSSBBBB'] is one object without a key, the object contains an array!

```
try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("[0,'000SSSBBBB']");
        String obj = (String)jsonArray.get(1);
        ...
    }catch(org.json.JSONException e){}
```